# Sharing a 3D int array between processes C/C++

Tags: c++, c, shared-memory

I'm currently modifing a code which uses a cache loaded on the fly from a database. The `cache[s][r]` dimensions are indexes which holds an array with the loaded data.

The following code generates the two first dimensions as a **1D** array. Using `((x * max_len) + y)` to access, but I will represent it here as `cache[s][r]`.

```
cacheId = shmget(key, s * r * sizeof (int*), IPC_CREAT | 0666);
cache = (int **)shmat(cacheId, 0, 0);
```

The problem is that when loading the data from the database and generating the third dimension with malloc, these are not shared.

There is any solution which doesn't need to generate a new key,shmget and shmat for each `cache[s][r]` combinations to alloc the 3th dim?

Thanks

Comment: If you need to allocate into shared memory, you can't use `malloc()` et al.  You have to manage the allocation yourself.  If you store any pointers in the shared memory, make sure that the shared memory is loaded at the same address in each process.

Comment: What kind if multi process application do you have? MPI ist designed  for the communication between processes.

Comment: take a look at [Boost.Interprocess](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/doc/html/interprocess.html), it will do the hard work for you

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler I know that.

Comment: @schorsch312 Its a really big application and i'm just modifiying a little part of it.

Comment: @Massimiliano Janes Boost.Interprocess seems the way to go. I'm trying to build my data structure with boost vectors and allocates but i'm unable to make it work, it always crash on the resize. Do you know any working example with vector of vectors or 3d vectors?

Comment: have you read [this](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/doc/html/interprocess/allocators_containers.html#interprocess.allocators_containers.containers_explained.containers_of_containers) ?